# How to check if a specific app has admin rights, and go to its admin screen?

Tags: android, android-intent, settings, admin

### Background

Android apps can gain some special rights using admin policies, like turning the lock screen on.

As such, those apps cannot be uninstalled till the user has revoked their admin rights.

I wish to have a function that will check if a given app (given a package name of the app) has admin rights, and if so, i will open the admin settings page of this app, to allow the user to revoke its rights.

### The problem

As it turns out, there is already a function that does it.

First you get an instance of the DevicePolicyManager :

```
DevicePolicyManager dpm=(DevicePolicyManager)context.getSystemService(Context.DEVICE_POLICY_SERVICE);
```

Then you are supposed to call [**isAdminActive**](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/admin/DevicePolicyManager.html#isAdminActive%28android.content.ComponentName%29) , and get a result of true/false.

However, this function's parameter is ComponentName, meaning it needs not only the package name, but also the path to a specific class of the app.

An alternative would be to query all active admin apps, using [**getActiveAdmins**](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/admin/DevicePolicyManager.html#getActiveAdmins%28%29).

Later, I you can go to the admin page using:

```
final Intent intent=new Intent();
intent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.android.settings","com.android.settings.DeviceAdminSettings"));
startActivity(intent);
```

or even more specifically, to enable/disable the app admin rights :

```
final Intent intent=new Intent();
intent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.android.settings","com.android.settings.DeviceAdminAdd"));
intent.putExtra(DevicePolicyManager.EXTRA_DEVICE_ADMIN,componentName);
activity.startActivity(intent);
```

However, both of those ways seems a bit hacky, as they do not use the official API of android, that could change over android versions and roms.

### The question

What's the best way to check if a given app (package name) has admin rights?

What's the best way to go to the admin page ? is there a safer way to go there? maybe a fallback mechanism from what i've done to the security screen intent (which for some reason I can't find in the API) ?

---

### The answer

After reading the answer on this post, I've decided to share the findings:

If you wish to be safe, you can tell the user to go to the admin screen by himself, and only guide him to the security screen:

```
intent=new Intent(Settings.ACTION_SECURITY_SETTINGS);
context.startActivity(intent);
```

however, i think the next way should work for all devices:

```
Intent intent=new Intent(DevicePolicyManager.ACTION_ADD_DEVICE_ADMIN);
final PackageManager packageManager=context.getPackageManager();
final List<ResolveInfo> resolveInfos=packageManager.queryIntentActivities(intent,0);
if(resolveInfos!=null&&!resolveInfos.isEmpty())
  try
    {
    final ResolveInfo resolveInfo=resolveInfos.get(0);
    intent=new Intent();
    intent.setComponent(new ComponentName(resolveInfo.activityInfo.packageName,resolveInfo.activityInfo.name));
    intent.putExtra(DevicePolicyManager.EXTRA_DEVICE_ADMIN,componentNameResult);
    context.startActivity(intent);
    return true;
    }
  catch(final Exception e)
    {}
```

and if it fails, you can always use any of the methods i've written, and in the end, call the safe one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Android apps can gain some special rights using admin policies, like turning on/off the screen.

A `DevicePolicyManager` can lock the screen with `lockNow()` and set the lock timeout via `setMaximumTimeToLock()`, if that's what you mean.

> What's the best way to check if a given app (package name) has admin rights?

See if they are in the roster returned by `getActiveAdmins()`. That method returns `null` or `List` of `ComponentName` objects, and you can call `getPackageName()` on a `ComponentName` to compare it to your target package.

> What's the best way to go to the admin page ?

There is no documented and supported way to get to this portion of the Settings app. The closest thing [is `ACTION_SECURITY_SETTINGS`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.html#ACTION_SECURITY_SETTINGS).

Comment: yes i meant the lock screen. i didn't remember exactly. fixed it now. anyway, that's not the point and it's just a background to what i wish to achieve. about "getActiveAdmins", that's one of the things i've written. i asked if there is a better way. about the ACTION_SECURITY_SETTINGS, this could be a nice thing to fallback to in case none of what i've written works.

Comment: @androiddeveloper: "that's one of the things i've written" -- I know, but you asked how to do it. "i asked if there is a better way" -- what criteria would you suggest for deciding what is "better"? Also, if you read what you wrote, you did not ask if there is a "better" way. You asked what is the "best" way. And, since `getActiveAdmins()` is the *only* way I know of, by definition, it is the best way that I know of.

Comment: i've written about "isAdminActive" , so i thought maybe there is a similar way, but that just takes the package name instead of the whole component name. i guess that even if there was a better way, it would work using a similar implementation (maybe using a hashmap of package name against component name, but about the same). i asked if there is a better/best way in general for the whole process, including this step (as i've introduce in the background section). before I tick this answer, do you think it's ok to use the fallback mechanism i've offered - try the risky methods and then API's?

Comment: @androiddeveloper: "but that just takes the package name instead of the whole component name" -- that's because it only works for your own app. "do you think it's ok to use the fallback mechanism i've offered - try the risky methods and then API's?" -- I wouldn't use the risky methods at all, because I avoid undocumented and unsupported means like the plague. That being said, if that activity has an `<intent-filter>` with a custom, but undocumented, action string, that'd be more reliable than hoping they don't rename the class.

Comment: about the packageName, I see. about the risky part, it was hard enough to find those. where can i find the manifest that points to them?

Comment: @androiddeveloper: In the AOSP code. Here's the 4.4.2 manifest for Settings: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Settings/+/android-4.4.2_r1/AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: hmmm... maybe I could check which activity is responsible for "ADD_DEVICE_ADMIN" , and do what i've done here, instead of putting the paths hard coded, right? also, it seems google wishes to allow old intents to run the new activities, since they wrote "Keep compatibility with old shortcuts." for DeviceAdminSettings.

Comment: i've succeeded with what you've told me and added the solution. thank you for your time.